# Calculating number of permutations of a matrix with elements being adjacent integers only

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, integer

I'm trying to write a Python code in order to determine the number of possible permutations of a matrix where neighbouring elements can only be adjacent integer numbers. I also wish to know how many times each total set of numbers appears (by that I mean, the same numbers of each integer in n matrices, but not in the same matrix permutation)

Forgive me if I'm not being clear, or if my terminology isn't ideal! Consider a 5 x 5 zero matrix. This is an acceptable permutaton, as all of the elements are adjacent to an identical number.

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0

25 x 0, 0 x 1, 0 x 2
```

The elements within the matrix can be changed to 1 or 2. Changing any of the elements to 1 would also be an acceptable permutation, as the 1 would be surrounded by an adjacent integer, 0. For example, changing the central [2,2] element of the matrix:

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0
0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0


24 x 0, 1 x 1, 0 x 2
```

However, changing the [2,2] element in the centre to a 2 would mean that all of the elements surrounding it would have to switch to 1, as 2 is not adjacent to 0.

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  1  1  1  0
0  1  2  1  0
0  1  1  1  0
0  0  0  0  0

16 x 0, 8 x 1, 1 x 2
```

I want to know how many permutations are possible from that zeroed 5x5 matrix by changing the elements to 1 and 2, whilst keeping neighbouring elements as adjacent integers. In other words, any permutations where 0 and 2 are adjacent are not allowed.

I also wish to know how many matrices contain a certain number of each integer. For example, both of the below matrices would be 24 x 0, 1 x 1, 0 x 2. Over every permutation, I'd like to know how many correspond to this frequency of integers.

```
0  0  0  0  0        0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0        0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0        1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0        0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0        0  0  0  0  0
```

Again, sorry if I'm not being clear or my nomenclature is poor! Thanks for your time - I'd really appreciate some help with this, and any words or guidance would be kindly received.

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: This is an interesting question, but as it is combinatorial in nature it might be a better fit at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response ajcr. I am very new to this site and I was unaware that a devoted board for mathematics problems existed ... but as they say, ignorance is no excuse! :)

Comment: Also you suppose to do something. No one likes being dumped with a problem that you want to be solved, but spent 0 time solving by yourself.

Comment: Salvador Dali, you're working on the erroneous assumption that I've put no time into this problem myself. I can assure you my attempts have been quite extensive but have thus far failed. Why would I post lines of Python code that do not work? Perhaps this is standard procedure - as I said I am new - and if so, I apologise. I understand your perspective, but thinly veiled passive aggression is not necessary when I've only kindly requested for a fresh pair of eyes to look at the problem.

Comment: @Sam Have you read the help pages? [help], [faq], and [mcve]?

Comment: @Sam Currently I see this "here is my problem and what I want to have. Go and solve it". How exactly (and why) from this can I guess that you have done extensive attempts if no attempts were shown? If you spent so much time working on something, you can at least describe you approaches and how they failed at least so that other people would not try them and waste their time.

Comment: Does this have to come up with every dynamic programming problem?  @ajcr, this problem belongs here and you don't realize it because you don't know the needed programming technique.

Comment: @SalvadorDali The problem in this case is that Sam does not know the standard technique called "dynamic programming", and without knowing that he has no hope of figuring out how to get started.  If you were familiar with dynamic programming yourself, you would know that this is common for people who don't know dynamic programming when they need to do dynamic programming.

Comment: @btilly I frequently win various programming competitions, so most probably I know what is dynamic programming and this is not at all a hard concept that requires huge amount of knowledge. Back to the topic: not knowing something is not an excuse not to show what attempts you have taken to solve the problem (especially if you claim that you have done a lot of attempts).

Comment: OK, you're familiar with dynamic programming.  Have you never seen someone completely stuck with where to start on a dynamic programming problem?

Comment: @btilly: I am also familiar with dynamic programming, thank you. The way the question was phrased initially made me think that the OP was tackling the problem from the enumerative combinatorics angle. My comment only meant to highlight an alternative forum where it could be asked in this  context (I did not mean to imply that it was off topic here).

Answer (score 0):

First, what you're calling a permutation isn't.

Secondly your problem is that a naive brute force solution would look at `3^25 = 847,288,609,443` possible combinations.  (Somewhat less, but probably still in the hundreds of billions.)

The right way to solve this is called dynamic programming.  What you need to do for your basic problem is calculate, for `i` from `0` to `4`, for each of the  different possible rows you could have there how many possible matrices you could have had that end in that row.

Add up all of the possible answers in the last row, and you'll have your answer.

For the more detailed count, you need to divide it by row, by cumulative counts you could be at for each value.  But otherwise it is the same.

The straightforward version should require tens of thousands of operation.  The detailed version might require millions.  But this will be massively better than the hundreds of billions that the naive recursive version takes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful response btilly. I'll go away and look into dynamic programming and hopefully I can use it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for some more simple rules:
1s can be distributed arbitrarily in the array, since the matrix so far only consists of 0s. 2s can aswell be distributed arbitrarily, since only neighbouring elements must be either 1 or 2.

Thus there are `f(x) = n! / x!` possibilities to distributed 1s and 2s over the matrix.

So the total number of possible permutations is `2 * sum(x = 1 , n * n){f(x)}`.

Calculating the number of possible permutations with a fixed number of 1s can easily be solved by simple calculating `f(x)`.

The number of matrices with a fixed number of 2s and 1s is a bit more tricky. Here you can only rely on the fact that all mirrored versions of the matrix yield the same number of 1s and 2s and are valid. Apart from using that fact you can only brute-force search for correct solutions.